# Unity 2D collisions not being detected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been following the Unity 2D rougelike tutorials. The inspector returns no console errors when run.

The player moves on a grid and should collide with objects, some should trigger upon moving over them and others should prevent movement, the objects that activate upon trigger work as intended. The player has a Rigidbody 2D and Box Collider 2D and is set to is kinematic. The objects that do not work as intended are the walls, the outer walls should block movement entirely, the inner walls should be breakable and the enemies can not be damaged or damage the player. The walls all have a Box Collider 2D. The enemies also have a Rigidbody 2D and is set to is kinematic [Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKz6b.png)

Comment: So is your problem that the walls don't block the player?

Comment: @CNuts that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal that the walls don't block your player. You have set the `isKinematic` to true. What that does is

> Controls whether physics affects the rigidbody.

So when you set it to true, physics no longer affect your player and he will not collide with anything.

From the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html):

> If isKinematic is enabled, Forces, collisions or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore. The rigidbody will be under full control of animation or script control by changing transform.position.

You should set the `isKinematic` to false if you want your player to be able to colllide with different objects.

Comment: Hi @CNuts I turned the player's Is Kinematic to false but now a new a new problem has arisen.  The player will only move one place before being unable to move any further despite there being free spaces. Being able to move once space, I can see that the outer walls are behaving correctly now. Any moves made after the first move count as a move a reduce the players health count due to the health count being reduced by 1 per move but the player remains in the same position.

Comment: @FarhadKhan Sounds like there is an object that has a collider that is blocking the player path.

Comment: if I move the player to an empty space to the right or above, the player is unable to return to the starting position which the player moved from.

Comment: @FarhadKhan It's hard to find the reason of that since I don't have much information but the only reason i can think of is that there's something blocking his way. Maybe it appears after you move, try to check while you run your game what there is in those empty space.